# I want the code to return a string, but it is returning a value

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I am trying to use InputBox to have the user select a starting cell with a mouse click. I want to then store that address in a variable as a string.

```
Sub NumberFormatFromCell()


Dim rng As Range
Dim FormatRuleInput As String

'Get A Cell Address From The User to Get Number Format From
  On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
  Title:="Number Format Rule From Cell", _
  Prompt:="Select a starting cell", _
  Type:=8)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Test to ensure User Did not cancel
  If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set Variable to first cell in user's input (ensuring only 1 cell)
  Set rng = rng.Cells(1, 1)

  MsgBox (rng)

End Sub
```

When the code gets to `MsgBox(rng)`, it displays the value from the cell, not the address.

Comment: `MsgBox rng.address`

Answer (score 2):

Your code currently gets the value of the rng cell.  To get the address of the rng cell, call the cell's Address property, like so:

`MsgBox rng.address`